# How to sum second list from list of list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to sum from list of list as below

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5]]]
```

What i want is to sum like below

```
   [1,1,1]+[1,1,1]+[1,1,1]  = 9
   [2,2,2]+[2,2,2]+[2,2,2]  = 18
       ....                 = 27
                            = 36
                            = 45
```

And return a list like below as the final list:

```
[9,18,27,36,45]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.sum`

```
a = np.array([[[1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 4],
  [5, 5, 5]],

 [[1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 4],
  [5, 5, 5]],

 [[1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5]]])

res = np.sum(a, axis=(0,2))
# Does reduction along axis 0 and 2 by doing summation.
# numpy takes tuple of axis indices to do reduction 
# simultaneously along those axis.
print(res.tolist())
>> [ 9, 18, 27, 36, 45]
```

Comment: thanks , can you explain more on axis (0,2) please

Comment: @foy Summation will be done along axis 0 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
lis=np.array([[[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5]]])
print(lis.sum(axis=0).sum(axis=1))
easiest I think with numpy.
output
```

[ 9 18 27 36 45]

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()`

Code:

```
import numpy as np
lis=np.array([[[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5]]])
res=[]

for i in zip(*lis):
    res.append(sum(sum(i)))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[9, 18, 27, 36, 45]
```

**List comprehension**:

```
print([sum(sum(i)) for i in zip(*lis)]) #Same output.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [[[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [5, 5, 5]],

     [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5]]]

result = [sum(x)+sum(y)+sum(z) for x,y,z in zip(a[0], a[1], a[1])]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for answering your first question. Make sure to add a description of what your code does and how it answers the question!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).